# MDX, The employee with the highest sales per product and year

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, mdx, olap-cube, mdx-query

I´m learning MDX and OLAP with Visual Studi and Management Sql Server Studio. Actually I make a cube "Sales"

[image: it is the measure and dimensions of the cube Sales]

I´m tryig get "The employee with the highest sales per product and year" and I writed

```
With MEMBER measures.[Maximun Sales] AS 
 MAX(([Product].[ProductName].[ProductName],[Employee].[Geography].  [Employee]), [Measures].[Sales Amount])

 MEMBER measures.[EmpLoyee] AS TOPCOUNT(([Product].[ProductName].  [ProductName], [Employee].[Geography].[Employee]), 1, [Measures].[Sales    Amount]).ITEM(0).NAME

 SELECT { measures.[Maximun Sales], MEASUREs.[EmpLoyee]} ON COLUMNS,
 ([Product].[ProductName].[ProductName], [Order Date].[Calendar].[Year]) ON    ROWS
 FROM SALES
```

But the query didn´t work. Please, can someone help me?. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not the easiest for a beginner to understand. I have provided an example below from the Adventure Works cube. This query shows the top Customer by sales for every combination of Product and Year, which is similar to what you asked and you can hopefully adapt it.

```
SELECT
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
,   NON EMPTY
    GENERATE
    (
        {
        [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS
    *   [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
        }
    ,   (
        [Product].[Product].CURRENTMEMBER
    ,   [Date].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER
        )
    *   TOPCOUNT
        (
        [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
    ,   1
    ,   [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )       
    )
ON ROWS
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

**HOW IT WORKS**

You were right in thinking the TopCount function would help you. We want to get the Top 1 Customer by Sales for every Product / Year.

So our Top Count function gets our Top 1 Customer by Sales. How do we then apply this to every Product / Year? This is where the Generate function helps. This will apply our Top 1 Customer function across all Product / Year combinations.

You can think of the way the Generate function works as:

1) Get every combination of Product / Year

2) Get each combination one at a time

3) For each combination get the Top 1 Customer by Sales

4) Move onto the next combination

For a good explanation of this please see [here](http://bidn.com/Blogs/userid/17/fun-with-mdx-ndash-part-1-top-5-products-per-country). I would also recommend reading about the Generate function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/generate-mdx).